# Combining solar panels of equal voltages and unequal currents in parallel

Tags: voltage, power, current

I am currently working on a project that runs completely on pure green, solar energy. For that matter, I have four solar panels, all yielding the same voltage of 6 volts, while outputting a different current each.

For clarity, two of the solar panels are identical on terms of both voltage and current, hence the same power output, while the third is 6A, 36W panel, and the fourth is a 1.1 A, 7W solar panel.

My question is: Does connecting these four solar panels in parallel impact efficiency or not?

Comment: Are you planning to join them via (Schottky) diodes or directly? If the latter and one is shaded while the other is in sunlight, the shaded one will need to block the full voltage. I can't say how much of a problem or not that would be.

Comment: I am planning the former.

Comment: Then no issues apart from the added voltage drop. If you have any MPPT downstream, it may find a local maxima and miss the global one if the panels are unevenly lit. Wasting energy but nothing harmful.

Comment: _"two of the solar panels are identical on terms of both voltage and current"_ - what their specs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are combining panels that do not have the same I-V curve then it's not a good idea to put them in series or in parallel, it will affect efficiency and you could burn out a cell. If you have an MPPT tracker it will not find the right efficiency point if you have mismatched cells.